# Getting inconsistent accessibility error while trying to have protected constructor in base abstract class with interface injected marked as internal

Tags: c#

I have 1 interface IMetadata which i want to restrict access to only current assembly(class library) and not outside of that and hence I have marked it as internal.

Now I want to inject this interface to my base abstract class and call method of IMetadata on my base class method to perform some logic. Base class will receive versioning from derive class Type1 for instance hence i have marked base abstract class constructor as protected but I am getting below error :

> Inconsistent Accessibility : Parameter type IMetadata is less
>   accessible than BaseType.BaseType(IMetadata)

But this metadata will always going to receive its concrete type from derive class(Type1) hence I want this base class constructor as protected and also I want Metadata to be only available in current assembly and not outside of it.

```
internal interface IMetadata
{
   string CreateMetadata();
}

internal class Metadata : IMetadata
{
    public Metadata(string location)
    {       
          this.location = location;   
    }
    public string CreateMetadata()
    {
    }
}

public interface IBaseType
{ 
    Void Perform();
} 

public abstract class BaseType : IBaseType
{
   private readonly IMetadata _metadata;
   protected BaseType(IMetadata metadata) //error
   {

   }
}

class Type1 : BaseType
{
    public Type1(IMetadata metadata) : 
    base(metadata)
    {
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me whats the problem and how do I achieve this encapsulation?

Comment: A `public` thing can't have a dependency (e.g. constructor parameter) that isn't `public`. `IMetadata` needs to be `public`. The error basically explains that to you.

Comment: @mjwills But then the problem will be IMetadata will be accessed outside of my assembly which i am trying to avoid.Is there any way to achieve both(preventing access of Imetadata outside and also having protected constructor on base abstract class)?

Comment: No there isn't. A `public` / `protected` thing can't be dependent on an `internal` thing. I mean, what would the point of that be? You may as well just make it `internal`, since it won't be useful outside of the assembly anyway.

Comment: @mjwills Do you think that this is a design flaw which have created this problem?

Comment: It is very hard to give concrete advice when your code is so abstract. `BaseType`, `IMetadata`, `Type1` etc etc.

Comment: @mjwills - it's fine for a `public` *class* to have `internal` dependencies. It's just got to do it in a non-leaky fashion.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Non leaky fashion indicates design problem or not best practice?

Comment: No, hiding implementation details from consumers is a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the compiler performs these accessibility checks is to try to steer you into the ["pit of success"](https://medium.com/@ricomariani/the-pit-of-success-cfefc6cb64c8). You have "thingy" that you've marked (or allowed to default) as `internal`. That means it's an *implementation detail* within your assembly. Nothing outside of your assembly should know or care what this "thingy" is. It certainly won't be able to "say it's name" or create one.

You then write something that is `public` or `protected`. These are things which *are* visible to other assemblies. And then you're saying "in order to use this, you have to supply a thingy". You've leaked an implementation detail and that's why the compiler stops you. You need to look hard at this and either decide that it's *not* purely an implementation detail (and so make it `public`) or that you shouldn't be exposing it outside of your assembly.

Ideally you mark this constructor as [`private protected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private-protected) which carries the correct semantics - only the *intersection* of {classes inheriting from this class} and {classes within this assembly} can call it. Only other members of your assembly can get hold of the required instance anyway.

However, if you're not yet on C#7.2, you have to make a choice. I'd go with `internal`. It's an abstract class anyway, nobody can directly construct it even with a constructor that notionally isn't related to the inheritance hierarchy.

---

This compiles just fine and shows both approaches:

```
internal interface IMetadata
{
  string CreateMetadata();
}

internal class Metadata : IMetadata
{
  private readonly string location;
  public Metadata(string location)
  {
    this.location = location;
  }
  public string CreateMetadata()
  {
    return string.Empty;
  }
}

public interface IBaseType
{
  void Perform();
}

public abstract class BaseType : IBaseType
{
  private readonly IMetadata _metadata;
  private protected BaseType(IMetadata metadata) //No error
  {

  }

  internal BaseType(IMetadata metadata, int thing) //No error
  {

  }

  public abstract void Perform();
}

class Type1 : BaseType
{
  public Type1(IMetadata metadata) :
  base(metadata)
  {
  }

  public Type1(IMetadata metadata, int thing) : base(metadata, thing)
  {

  }

  public override void Perform()
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and for your valuable time and insights

Comment: Do you think having public constructor inside internal class make sense in case of Metadata class?Just trying to learn some good practices :)

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow - in an `internal` class, `public` and `internal` members mean practically the same thing. I'll often mark such members as `public` by default even though the reality is that they're really only `internal`.

Comment: In Advance Build setting of my project class library,I have already selected "c# major latest version(default)" still I am getting error feature private protected is not available in c# 7.0

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow - I slightly misspoke, it's a 7.2 feature (as indicated in the linked documentation) so you need to move to "latest minor" or at least 7.2.

Comment: I have upgraded to latest c# version.Is there any performance benefit of doing this or just the benefit to avail new features offered by c# language?

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time and for your kind efforts towards helping me.Appreciated :)